# Spring boot back end with Swing client

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-boot

I have a design question: I use DB + Hibernate + SpringBoot as back end in a server and use Swing clients on desktops.

I am considering for a new project the following architecture:

Back end (maybe in separate servers):

- SQL DB
- Spring Boot + Hibernate Java App

Front end(s):

- Swing Java App
- later: mobile App; Browser

I have searched a bit, but still have some doubts and feel I am missing something. I initially considered using React for front end. But this is going to take too long for me and I have lots of Swing components that I already optimized (and this my applications tend to use lots of grids with edits "in place")

I searched for Spring + Swing, but what I found was about running everything on the same JVM. I would think that separating them would allow me to (later) build a Mobile or Web front end using the same back end.

To sum it up:

1. create back end services with spring boot + hibernate on top of SQL db
2. create Swing front end that consumes those services
3. (later stage) mobile app to consume these same services

Questions:

1. Is this a good approach ? Am I seeing this the wrong way
2. How to "share" the POJOs between the back end and the front end? (thinking about placing the models on a separate lib); I don't mean how to transport them, I mean how to reuse them on both projects.

Comment: Spring Boot is a http server so ideally you are NOT to share any POJOs between your Swing client and Spring Boot server in any other way than making http requests.
For that you will need some kind of http client in your Swing application. 
This approach also means that you will be able to implement any other client and won't have to change your backend but simply define the API contracts from the very beginning.
For example, you may use Apache Http Client - https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

Comment: Say I have a class Product {id, code, description}. In the backend I retrieve it from the DB and marshall it to the client. Should'nt I have also a Product on the client? It does not need to be the "same" Product class but if it could be I would save some time.

Comment: are you successful in creating your project? Can you briefly describe what problems you encountered? ps, I'm going your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible.

1. I would create the backend application with Spring Boot and access a datastore with [Spring DATA](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data). I would make services available via [REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/).
2. To access REST from your Swing client you must use a REST client of some sort. I would recommend [Spring RestTemplate](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) but there are many alternatives.

> Synchronous client to perform HTTP requests, exposing a simple,
>   template method API over underlying HTTP client libraries such as the
>   JDK HttpURLConnection, Apache HttpComponents, and others.

3. Since you want mobile support some time in the future you could consider creating a webclient instead and making it cross platform (browser only).

**To answer your two questions:**

1. Regarding backend you will be perfectly fine as Spring Boot is a good option. As for the client I personally would not choose Swing today since it is very old and rather go for JavaFX 2 or a web client if that is an option. If you are the only developer and since you are proficient it might be a good solution for you.
2. You can share the POJOs from you Server for your Client as an api that you include as dependency. However it is usually [not recommended](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/366235/ways-to-share-dto-across-microservices) to share POJOs but rather generate it on the client side or just type them. In your case if it is a small project it probably is ok. Do what is most easy for you.

I would recommend start using Maven as a build tool if you do not already.

Good luck.

Comment: tks for the reply. So I would develop another (compatible) POJO on the frontend, I understand that i would not need the annotations so it would be cleaner but seems to be a duplicated effort. I suppose I could build the WSDL from the backend and import it via JAX,

Comment: Please, don't use WSDL, you are definitely making your life a nightmare. Use plain Java POJOs and share them as a lib.
As stated by Avec, the easiest solution is to build a maven project, with three sub-modules: /backend, where Spring would be implemented, /frontend that would be your Swing client and /common where you'd share all your common definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Your request is perfectly valid, as you are a Swing developer and your approach is absolutely fine.

So let's draw the general picture: you're building a backend/frontend product/software.

**Backend**

Your backend will be a Spring application that will run on a server, let's say http://localhost:8080, serving requests to clients.

You'd probably want to create a @RestController on http://localhost:8080/api/... to expose your functions to your Swing client.

**Swing client**

Your client will be a Swing application running on your desktop.

To connect your client to the Spring application, you now need to implement a service in your Swing application that will call your Spring web server and fetch the resources from there.

To achieve this goal, may options exist:

1. Why not plain Java ? Use this [tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/restfull-java-client-with-java-net-url/) to call your Spring services.
2. Http components from [Apache](https://alvinalexander.com/java/java-apache-httpclient-restful-client-examples) are quite common.
3. Spring your app ! Spring API includes [RestTemplate](https://www.baeldung.com/rest-template) that you can use in your Swing app to call Spring backend and fetch resources for your desktop app.

As you can see, this is EXACTLY the same thing as with a website in React:

- your web page is the JFrame
- your JSX components in React would be your JPanels and components
- you'd connect action listeners on components (JComboBox, JButton) to a service calling your Spring backend.
- you'd then use the resources fetched from your Spring server to update your application state.
- rince and repeat

So, be confident, your approach is correct. You'll find people ranting at you having chosen an obsolete techno but really, who cares?

(May I add, totally a pun, you've been smarter than the JavaFX guys which are now facing the segregation of javafx libraries from the core Java ;-))

And as always... happy coding !